# Trouble comparing time with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rspec, comparison

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and the rspec-rails gem 2.14. For a my object I would like to compare the current time with the `updated_at` object attribute after a controller action run, but I am in trouble since the spec does not pass. That is, given the following is the spec code:

```
it "updates updated_at attribute" do
  Timecop.freeze

  patch :update
  @article.reload
  expect(@article.updated_at).to eq(Time.now)
end
```

When I run the above spec I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@article.updated_at).to eq(Time.now)

   expected: 2013-12-05 14:42:20 UTC
        got: Thu, 05 Dec 2013 08:42:20 CST -06:00

   (compared using ==)
```

How can I make the spec to pass?

---

*Note*: I tried also the following (note the `utc` addition):

```
it "updates updated_at attribute" do
  Timecop.freeze

  patch :update
  @article.reload
  expect(@article.updated_at.utc).to eq(Time.now)
end
```

but the spec still does not pass (note the "got" value difference):

```
Failure/Error: expect(@article.updated_at.utc).to eq(Time.now)

   expected: 2013-12-05 14:42:20 UTC
        got: 2013-12-05 14:42:20 UTC

   (compared using ==)
```

Comment: It is comparing the object ids, hence the text from inspect is matching, but underneath you have two different Time objects. You could just use `===`, but that may suffer from crossing second boundaries. Probably best is to find or write your own matcher, in which you convert to epoch seconds and allow for a small absolute difference.

Comment: If I understood you relating "crossing second boundaries", the problem should not arise since I am using the [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem that "freezes" the time.

Comment: Ah I missed that, sorry. In which case, just use `===` instead of `==` - currently you are comparing the object_id of two different Time objects. Although Timecop won't freeze database server time . . . so if your timestamps are being generated by the RDBMS it wouldn't work (I expect that is not a problem for you here though)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Ruby Time object maintains greater precision than the database does.  When the value is read back from the database, it’s only preserved to microsecond precision, while the in-memory representation is precise to nanoseconds.

If you don't care about millisecond difference, you could do a to_s/to_i on both sides of your expectation

```
expect(@article.updated_at.utc.to_s).to eq(Time.now.to_s)
```

or

```
expect(@article.updated_at.utc.to_i).to eq(Time.now.to_i)
```

Refer to [this](https://tddium.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/) for more information about why the times are different

Comment: As you can see in the code from the question, I use the `Timecop` gem. Should it just solve the issue by "freezing" the time?

Comment: You save the time in the database and retrieve it(@article.updated_at) which makes it loose the nanoseconds where as Time.now has retains the nanosecond. It should be clear from the first few lines of my answer

Comment: The accepted answer is nearly a year older than the answer below - the be_within matcher is a much better way of handling this: A) you don't need a gem; B) it works for any type of value (integer, float, date, time, etc.); C) it's natively part of RSpec

Comment: This is an "OK" solution, but definitely the `be_within` is the right one

Comment: Hello I am using datetime comparisons with job enqueue delay expectations `expect {FooJob.perform_now}.to have_enqueued_job(FooJob).at(some_time)`

I'm not sure the `.at`matcher would accept a time converted to integer with `.to_i`anyone has faced this problem ?

Comment: This actually won't work because if the second falls between the times then then test will fail.

Answer (score 274):

I find using the `be_within` default rspec matcher more elegant:

```
expect(@article.updated_at.utc).to be_within(1.second).of Time.now
```

Comment: .000001 s is a bit tight. I tried even .001 and it was failing sometimes. Even .1 seconds I think proves that the time is being set to now. Good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I think this answer is better because it expresses the intent of the test, rather than obscuring it behind some unrelated methods like `to_s`. Also, `to_i` and `to_s` might fail infrequently if the time is near the end of a second.

Comment: Looks like the `be_within` matcher was added to RSpec 2.1.0 on November 7, 2010, and enhanced a few times since then. http://rspec.info/documentation/2.14/rspec-expectations/file.Changelog.html

Comment: I get `undefined method 'second' for 1:Fixnum`. Is there something I need to `require`?

Comment: @DavidMoles `.second` is a rails extension: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html

Comment: This is nice. You could change this to use `updated_at` and then `Time.zone.now` if you don't want to convert to `utc` every time. And it keeps Rubocop happy.

Answer (score 18):

Old post, but I hope it helps anyone who enters here for a solution. I think it's easier and more reliable to just create the date manually:

```
it "updates updated_at attribute" do
  freezed_time = Time.utc(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0) #Put here any time you want
  Timecop.freeze(freezed_time) do
    patch :update
    @article.reload
    expect(@article.updated_at).to eq(freezed_time)
  end
end
```

This ensures the stored date is the right one, without doing `to_x` or worrying about decimals.

Comment: Make sure you unfreeze time at the end of the spec

Comment: Changed it to use a block instead. That way you can't forget about returning back to normal time.

Answer (score 11):

yep as `Oin` is suggesting `be_within` matcher is the best practice

...and it has some more uscases ->  http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/27-rspec-be_within-matcher

But one more way how to deal with this is to use Rails built in `midday` and `middnight` attributes.

```
it do
  # ...
  stubtime = Time.now.midday
  expect(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(stubtime)

  patch :update 
  expect(@article.reload.updated_at).to eq(stubtime)
  # ...
end
```

**Now this is just for demonstration !**

I wouldn't use this in a controller as you are stubbing all Time.new calls => all time attributes will have same time => may not prove concept you are trying to achive. I usually use it in composed Ruby Objects similar to this:

```
class MyService
  attr_reader :time_evaluator, resource

  def initialize(resource:, time_evaluator: ->{Time.now})
    @time_evaluator = time_evaluator
    @resource = resource
  end

  def call
    # do some complex logic
    resource.published_at = time_evaluator.call
  end
end

require 'rspec'
require 'active_support/time'
require 'ostruct'

RSpec.describe MyService do
  let(:service) { described_class.new(resource: resource, time_evaluator: -> { Time.now.midday } ) }
  let(:resource) { OpenStruct.new }

  it do
    service.call
    expect(resource.published_at).to eq(Time.now.midday)    
  end
end
```

But honestly I recommend to stick with `be_within` matcher even when comparing Time.now.midday !

So yes pls stick with `be_within` matcher ;)

---

**update 2017-02**

Question in comment:

> what if the times are in a Hash? any way to make expect(hash_1).to eq(hash_2) work when some hash_1 values are pre-db-times and the corresponding values in hash_2 are post-db-times? –

```
expect({mytime: Time.now}).to match({mytime: be_within(3.seconds).of(Time.now)}) `
```

you can pass any RSpec matcher to the `match` matcher
(so e.g. you can even do [API testing with pure RSpec](http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/30-pure-rspec-json-api-testing))

As for "post-db-times" I guess you mean  string that is generated after saving to DB. I would suggest decouple this case to 2 expectations (one ensuring hash structure, second checking the time) So you can do something like:

```
hash = {mytime: Time.now.to_s(:db)}
expect(hash).to match({mytime: be_kind_of(String))
expect(Time.parse(hash.fetch(:mytime))).to be_within(3.seconds).of(Time.now)
```

But if this  case is too often in your test suite I would suggest writing your [own RSpec matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher) (e.g. `be_near_time_now_db_string`) converting db string time to Time object and then use this as a part of the `match(hash)` :

```
 expect(hash).to match({mytime: be_near_time_now_db_string})  # you need to write your own matcher for this to work.
```

Comment: what if the times are in a Hash? any way to make `expect(hash_1).to eq(hash_2)` work when some hash_1 values are pre-db-times and the corresponding values in hash_2 are post-db-times?

Comment: I was thinking an arbitrary hash (my spec is asserting that an operation doesn't change a record at all). But thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way I found around this problem is to create a `current_time` test helper method like so:

```
module SpecHelpers
  # Database time rounds to the nearest millisecond, so for comparison its
  # easiest to use this method instead
  def current_time
    Time.zone.now.change(usec: 0)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SpecHelpers
end
```

Now the time is always rounded to the nearest millisecond to comparisons are straightforward:

```
it "updates updated_at attribute" do
  Timecop.freeze(current_time)

  patch :update
  @article.reload
  expect(@article.updated_at).to eq(current_time)
end
```

Comment: `.change(usec: 0)` is very helpful

Comment: We can use this `.change(usec: 0)` trick to solve the problem without using a spec helper too. If the first line is `Timecop.freeze(Time.current.change(usec: 0))` then we can simply compare `.to eq(Time.now)` at the end.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert the date/datetime/time object to a string as it's stored in the database with `to_s(:db)`.

```
expect(@article.updated_at.to_s(:db)).to eq '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
expect(@article.updated_at.to_s(:db)).to eq Time.current.to_s(:db)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I was comparing hashes, most of these solutions did not work for me so I found the easiest solution was to simply grab the data from the hash I was comparing. Since the updated_at times are not actually useful for me to test this works fine.

```
data = { updated_at: Date.new(2019, 1, 1,), some_other_keys: ...}

expect(data).to eq(
  {updated_at: data[:updated_at], some_other_keys: ...}
)
```

Comment: If `updated_at` is not useful for your use case, you can go for a more elegant solution instead of comparing it with itself:

`expect(data).to match(hash_including({ some_other_keys: ... }))`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.1+ you can use [Time Helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html):

```rb
include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

describe "some test" do
  around { |example| freeze_time { example.run } }

  it "updates updated_at attribute" do
    expect { patch :update }.to change { @article.reload.updated_at }.to(Time.current)
  end
end
```