# How to deal with TimeWithZone class when using change matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_read_status  
  def update_read_status
    if read_changed?
      column = read ? :read_at : :unread_at
      self[column] = Time.zone.now
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to test the code with this `RSpec`:

```
  context "#update_read_status" do
  before{ company.update_attributes(read_at: 2.months.ago) }
    context "when read become true" do
      it "read_at be current time" do
        expect{ company.update_attributes(read: true) }.to change{ company.read_at }.from(2.months.ago).to(Time.current)
      end
    end
  end
```

I know this spec fails because the time are changing during the test, but how can I compare time with `change` matcher?

I found a similar question [Trouble comparing time with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403063/trouble-comparing-time-with-rspec) , but the way with `to_s` method or `be_within` matcher is not available option in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_i` method to get time in seconds since Epoch and build the new Time with `Time.at` using those seconds as parameters. This will ignore that milliseconds who are messing with the test.

```
expect{ company.update_attributes(read: true) }
.to change{ Time.at(company.read_at.to_i) }
.from(2.months.ago).to(Time.at(Time.current.to_i))
```

Comment: I could pass the test by changing `2.months.ago` to `Time.new(2014,1,1)`. It didn't occurred to use `Ttime.at`. Thanks!